# ASP.NET MVC - Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined even if I'm including the library

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm trying to pass a value from my JavaScript to my Controller Action. Here's what I'm trying to do in my JavaScript :

```
function DoubleClick() {
    debugger;
    var id = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/GetAppId",
        data: { id: id}
    });
}
```

And my action (really simple action) :

```
public JsonResult GetAppId(int id)
{
    //some code will be included here
}
```

In my layout template, I'm including correctly my scripts (actually I'm using JS in some ohter pages and it works) :

```
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I'm opening the Chrome dev tool (F12), I'm seeing the following error message in the console tab :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I can't really see where the problem is. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery.Validate uses jQuery.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Should be like this:

```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As to why your JavaScript is not posting back the Value that is another error.

In Ajax you using "POST". Put a HttpPost Attribute on your method.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAppId(int id)
{
    //some code will be included here
}
```